# Error running ruby server with load error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I am very new to ruby. When I try to run by ruby application, I get this error:

```
$ ruby script/server
/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in      `require': cannot load such file -- script/../config/boot (LoadError)  
from /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in`require'     
from script/server:2:in `<main>'
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you post the second line of script/server file?

Comment: It looks like you're running an old rails app with a newer ruby

Comment: How can i get it run with older ruby. any command to degrade my ruby.ruby -v:ruby 1.9.3p392 (2013-02-22 revision 39386) [x86_64-linux]
rails -v:2.3.11 ,gem -v :1.8.23. Can you suggest for these

Comment: maybe the ruby version 1.8.7 works for you. simple install it with "rvm install 1.8.7". but I recommend to upgrade your rails application to a newer version.

Comment: Thanks Mattherick .this worked